# SQL Server : add reference number according other fields in record

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask a SQL question (I'm currently using SQL Server Management Studio).

```
CustomerID        ProductID         ProductName
------------------------------------------------------
111                 6577             ProductA
111                 6123             ProductB       
111                 1133             ProductC  
111                 1133             ProductC    
222                 6577             ProductA    
222                 6577             ProductA    
222                 1578             ProductL    
333                 9273             ProductX
```

and for the result, it will depend on the customerId and product ID to add the reference number in the other column.(for the same customer id if the product id is different the reference number will increment)

```
CustomerID        ProductID         ProductName        ref
-----------------------------------------------------------
111                 6577             ProductA          111-1
111                 6123             ProductB          111-2
111                 1133             ProductC          111-3
111                 1133             ProductC          111-3
222                 6577             ProductA          222-1
222                 6577             ProductA          222-1
222                 1578             ProductL          222-2
333                 9273             ProductX          333-1
```

I am not sure how to add the reference number by comparing the productid?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [**`dense_rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx):

```
select *
  , ref = convert(varchar(13),customerid) + '-'
      + convert(varchar(13),dense_rank() over (partition by customerid order by productname))
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UBXR81287

returns:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
| customerid | productid | productname |  ref  |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|        111 |      6577 | ProductA    | 111-1 |
|        111 |      6123 | ProductB    | 111-2 |
|        111 |      1133 | ProductC    | 111-3 |
|        111 |      1133 | ProductC    | 111-3 |
|        222 |      6577 | ProductA    | 222-1 |
|        222 |      6577 | ProductA    | 222-1 |
|        222 |      1578 | ProductL    | 222-2 |
|        333 |      9273 | ProductX    | 333-1 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DECLARE @sampledata AS TABLE 
(
CustomerID int,      
ProductID  int
)

INSERT INTO @sampledata VALUES (111, 6577),(111,6123  ),(111,1133 ),(111 ,1133)

SELECT *, 
       CONCAT(s.CustomerID,'-',CAST(dense_rank() over(PARTITION BY s.CustomerID ORDER BY s.ProductID DESC) AS varchar(10))) AS ref
FROM @sampledata s
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dense_rank() function

```
select *, concat(customerId, '-', dense_rank() over(partition by Customerid order by ProductName)) from #yourCustomer
```

Your Table:

```
create table #yourCustomer (CustomerId int, ProductId int, ProductName varchar(20))

insert into #yourCustomer (CustomerId, ProductId, ProductName) values
 (111      ,        6577      ,'ProductA')
,(111      ,        6123      ,'ProductB')       
,(111      ,        1133      ,'ProductC')  
,(111      ,        1133      ,'ProductC')    
,(222      ,        6577      ,'ProductA')    
,(222      ,        6577      ,'ProductA')    
,(222      ,        1578      ,'ProductL')    
,(333      ,        9273      ,'ProductX')
```

Answer (score 1):

The dense rank answers are all very good and provide exactly what you've asked for.

But there is a potential banana-skin;  If you introduce a new product, at some point in the future, and then rerun the `Ref` logic, you will get different results.

If the format of `Ref` does not matter, consider concatenating the `CustomerId` and `ProductId`.  Examples: 111-1 becomes 111-6577.  222-2 becomes 222-1578.

If the format is important, consider creating a Product table (`ProductId`, `ProductName`, `ProductRef`).  `Ref` would then equal `CustomerId` + `-` + `ProductRef`.  Example:

```
ProductId   ProductName     ProductRef 
6577        ProductA        1
6123        ProductB        2
1133        ProductC        3
```